# how to use echo or printf with xargs to iterate over a list from a file?

Tags: bash, text-processing, scripting, xargs, printf

In [poking about](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/658934/101935) with `xargs`, as here:

```
nicholas@gondor:~/x$ 
nicholas@gondor:~/x$ xargs echo < list.txt
1 2 3
nicholas@gondor:~/x$ 
nicholas@gondor:~/x$ cat list.txt 


1
2
3


nicholas@gondor:~/x$
```

how would `xargs` give output like:

```
number is 1
number is 2
number is 3
```

rather than just the numbers as is currently the result?

I tried using the `$` symbol with echo, but wasn't getting the correct output.

also tried:

```
nicholas@gondor:~/x$ 
nicholas@gondor:~/x$ printf '%s\n' "${list.txt[@]}" | xargs
bash: ${list.txt[@]}: bad substitution

nicholas@gondor:~/x$
```

but that's apparently not reading in the file correctly.

Would prefer to use `echo` over `printf` unless it's overly awkward.

another attempt:

```
nicholas@gondor:~/x$ 
nicholas@gondor:~/x$ xargs echo 'numbers are ${}' < list.txt
numbers are ${} 1 2 3
nicholas@gondor:~/x$
```

but not sure how to get each number above on a separate line.

see also:

[Printing an array to a file with each element of the array in a new line in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/125632/101935)

[echo list / array to xargs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/471461/101935)

Comment: there are dozens, if not hundreds, of bash tutorials on the net.  i suggest you go through one or more them - completing the exercises as you go - and gain a basic understanding of shell scripting.  your recent questions suggest you lack that fundamental understanding.   https://duckduckgo.com/?q=bash+tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ xargs printf 'Number is %d\n' <file
Number is 1
Number is 2
Number is 3
```

This reads words from your file and calls the given utility with as many words as possible at a time.  The `printf` utility will reuse its format string for each set of arguments.

The above would end up executing

```bsh
printf 'Number is %d\n' 1 2 3
```

If you have spaces or tabs on the lines in your file:

```
$ cat file
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

```
$ xargs printf 'Number is %s\n' <file
Number is 1
Number is 2
Number is 3
Number is 4
Number is 5
Number is 6
```

The above is the result of running the `printf` utility with each whitespace-delimited word from you file, i.e.,

```bsh
printf 'Number is %s\n' 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

```
$ xargs -I {} printf 'Number is %s\n' {} <file
Number is 1 2
Number is 3 4
Number is 5 6
```

The above runs `printf` three times, each with a separate line from your file.  Each `{}` in the utility's argument list will be replaced by a line read from your file.

If you file contains *quoted strings*:

```
'1 2'
'3 4'
'5 6'
```

Then:

```
$ xargs printf 'Number is %s\n' <file
Number is 1 2
Number is 3 4
Number is 5 6
```

The above is the result of running the equivalent of

```bsh
printf 'Number is %s\n' '1 2' '3 4' '5 6'
```